# Can not connect database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

There are 2-3 same questions on this site but none of them gave me the right answer so i am asking it again.

I have just installed codeigniter yesterday and was watching some tutorial. But when i tried to access database i started to get the following error

```
        Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

           Filename: C:\wamp\www\test\system\database\DB_driver.php

              Line Number: 124
```

I changed nothing  in the settings. Just installed wamp server and then created a database named asik and then created a table name bcc. Here is the database.php file:

```
     $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
     $db['default']['username'] = 'root';
     $db['default']['password'] = 'root';
     $db['default']['database'] = 'asik';
     $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
     $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
     $db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
     $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
     $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
     $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
     $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
     $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
     $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
     $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
     $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

(I also auto loaded the database.)

This is what I did before getting the error. I have tried all day and could not find any way to solve it. Please advise.

Comment: is the password 'root' or just a blank ''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be watching scratch video tutorials from youtube. Its really great for beginners. I faced the same problem.

Anyway the answer will be

```
   $db['default']['password'] = '';
```

If you do not use any password for the database then you don't have to use any password but username should be root.

Comment: In the tutorial they showed the password should be root and it worked for them. But it did not work for me. Anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

only verify username, password, database name and one line above these configs

```
$active_group = 'default';
```